# How to downgrade MobileFirst 7.1 to Worklight 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Currently in eclipse Mobile First 7.1 is installed. We are trying to downgrade it to worklight 6.1. We are using archive feature in eclipse (using zip) to downgrade it to 6.1. We are not getting any error while installation but eclipse is still showing MobileFirst 7.1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on exactly you're doing there that you think you've downgraded, but note that *downgrading is not possible*. You cannot downgrading after upgrading your project, as the upgrade *changes the application code*.

I hope you made a copy of your project before upgrading.